# Generic WeakReference proxy

Tags: c#, generics, weak-references, proxy-classes

I want to create custom `WeakReference<T>` which would implement an interface passed as generic parameter `T`.

Usage:

```
interface IInterface
{
    void SomeMethod(bool param);
}

public class Subject : IInterface { /*...*/ }

var proxyRef = new ProxyWeakReference<IInterface>(new Subject());
proxyRef.SomeMethod(false);
IInterface subject = proxyRef.Target;
```

Is there any already created solutions to do that? Or what i should use to create such type of proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, You are looking for a [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4)